# How does a lexer return a semantic value that the parser uses?

Tags: yacc, lexical-analysis

Is it always necessary to do so?  What does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Lexers don't deal with semantics, they only deal with turning a stream of characters into tokens (sequences of characters that have meaning to the compiler). Semantics are determined  during syntactic analysis. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419269/what-happens-when-i-compile/1419294#1419294) to a previous question for further details on the stages of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Lexer don't care about semantic the only mission in life for lexers is to convert the source code (stream of characters) into tokens each has this form `<Token_type, Information_related_to_token>` the information maybe the value of the token (string), the name of the operator (=) ...

Tokens then are sent to a parser that deals with syntactic analysis. as a side job a lexer can create a symbols table.

Answer (score 0):

In `yacc`, your lexer gets a global variable named `yylval` which is a C union.  Back in yacc, this becomes the value for `$1`, `$2`, etc.